# CNAME запись к domain

Tags: cname

Имеется такой вопрос, нужно чтоб один домен ссылался на другой через CNAME запись, оба домена находятся в разных DNS зонах и ничего общего между собой не имеют, возможно что при вводе apps.domain1.com я видел тоже самое что и на app.domain2.com? при этом чтоб URL был тот на который изначально зашел, никаких 301 redirect не нужно который перекинет на другой домен. Надо так чтоб зашел на app.domain2.com и видел там apps.domain1.com, доступ к обоим доменам естественно есть а так-же и root, вопрос как такое провернуть? то есть это получается некая iframe логика, но через CNAME.

Comment: не понимаю причем тут iframe какие то. просто делаете CNAME запись и настраиваете правильную реакцию на доменное имя в web-сервере

Comment: iframe не причем, это просто для понимания того что один домен должен отображать другой домен, так суть вопроса и заключается как это сделать, я понимаю что и "настраиваете правильную реакцию" как ее настроить?

Comment: Это зависит от того, какой вы используете web-сервер. А вы в вопросе об этом ни слова не сказали. например для апача боле менее современных версий достаточно в описании сервера указать `ServerAlias второе-имя`. для nginx вам уже написали. так же можно просто продублировать весь блок описания с другим именем домена. И разумеется, если на сайте где то используются страницы где полностью указано имя домена в ссылках все эти ссылки надо менять на относительные, что бы работали с любым доменом. то же касается и любых cgi-скриптов

Comment: да пардон веб-сервер апач, спасибо почитаю про ServerAlias =)

Answer (score 0):

Не вижу проблем. В домене 1 пишете

```
cname apps app.domain2.com
```

В домене 2 должен существовать поддомен app.

В nginx домена 2 надо добавить:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name apps.domen1.com;
    rewrite ^(.*) http://app.domen2.com$1 permanent;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Не обратил внимания на то, что в вопросе требуется при переходе на второй домен сохранить в адресной строке имя первого домена. Теоретически невозможно зафиксировать имя домена в адресной строке, если идет смена домена. Все браузеры запрещают такие манипуляции с адресной строкой из соображений безопасности. Вопрос нерешаемый.

Comment: Вот можете посмотреть на живом примере: test.millersoils.lv перекидывает на test.kagg.eu

Comment: да но мне не нужно чтоб куда-то перекидывало, надо чтоб оставался на test.milersoils.lv и на нем отображал test.kagg.eu (без редиректов)

Comment: А это теоретически невозможно, если идет смена домена. Все браузеры запрещают такие манипуляции с адресной строкой из соображений безопасности. Вопрос нерешаемый.